# Only Safari not showing site styles? Localhost or live server

Tags: css, safari

Working on a new site and it's not showing styles in Safari at all, localhost or live server.

Here is a link:
http://markszymanski.com/test/ab/

I'm using a few new tools on this project but can't find where this weird issue is coming from?
I'm using HTML 5 reset, jeet grid and regular scss.

Answer (score 0):

I found this line of code to be the culprit:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 200dpi),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 1.25dppx)
{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Took it from here http://www.intridea.com/blog/2014/5/8/better-font-smoothing-in-chrome-on-mac-os-x